# making prediction on the entire testset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I want to make predictions on the entire test set, here the test set is only 20% of datasetA, I understand that this is because its only for training purposes, when I save the weights and then make predictions on another datasetB, will it also split the test-set datasetB.
How can I make predictions on the entire test-set datasetB using the weights of datasetA that it was trained on.
Thanks.

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values

# Dependent Variable:
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 27, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 27, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 20)

#making predictions on test data
classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are asking 2 questions here:

First, the splitting of "dataset B" into a train and test set is done manually by you in the line
`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)`.

If, when you use your "dataset B", you want to test your classifier on ALL the data points of "dataset B", you do not have to do this train test split, and can simply pass the `X` values of "dataset B" to your classifier.

As for how to do this, as per your second question, it is the same as what you have already done with "dataset A"'s test set:

`classifier.predict(X)` will make predictions using the fit it already learned on "dataset A", assuming you do not recompile or call `.fit()` again.

Comment: These are two different steps you're describing - train_test_split is completely separate from saving the weights of the model. The other answer on this question shows one popular way of saving the weights, if that's what you would like to do, or you can directly use `.predict()`. What you use predict ON is a separate question, and you can choose to only use it on another sub set of "dataset B" or the whole dataset.

Comment: It depends what you want to do - recall from my answer that calling `.fit()` will retrain the weights. If you want to *keep* the weights you had from training on "dataset A", you should skip the call to fit and jump straight too `y_pred = ann.predict(x)`

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to use your trained model on a completely new dataset?

Keras provides several ways to do this, but I think the most common one would be to export your trained model into a .hd5 file using the command

```
model.save("filepath/model.hd5")
```

Now you can load in and use your model to wherever you want using the commands

```
model = model.load("filepath/model.hd5")
score = model.evaluate(X, Y)
```

where X is the feature columns of Dataset B and Y is the response to get your scoring. If dataset B is in the same instance, you can always just use

```
model.predict(X)
```

Where X is now the feature columns of dataset B